# python, pexpect: sendline() adding unexpected whitespace in sending text

Tags: python, linux, telnet, pexpect

I am using `python=2.7` and `pexpect=4.5.0` on ubuntu 16.04

This is the code:

```
telnet.sendline("ls --color=never | grep -v bootimage | xargs -n1 rm -rf")
```

I'm sending this line to an embedded linux machine from my ubuntu computer, i'm in a virutalenv.

However, what this embedded machine gets is:

```
ls --color=never | grep -v bootimage | xar gs -n1 rm -rf
```

I mean, why does `xargs` become `xar gs` ...??? How do I fix it?

*Note: 
1. I also send other shorter commands, they are good.
2. It used to be good. This does not happen consistently.*

Answer (score 0):

Using raw string maybe a better choice like `telnet.sendline(r"ls --color=never | grep -v bootimage | xargs -n1 rm -rf")`